# Change janus vim-ruby default hash indentation

Tags: ruby, vim, janus

Here is how vim-ruby installed by Janus currently indents a method with hash parameters:

```
my_method(foo: :bar,
          baz: {
  foo2: :bar2,
  foo3: :bar3,
}
```

I want it to be:

```
my_method(foo: :bar,
          baz: {
                 foo2: :bar2,
                 foo3: :bar3
          }
         )
```

How can I make that change in my `.vimrc.after`?

Comment: have you looked at this by chance? https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anthony mentions in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563778/change-janus-vim-ruby-default-hash-indentation#comment72261630_42563778), this appears to be a [vim-ruby issue](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/328).
I got around it by adding this to my `.vimrc.after`

```
let g:ruby_indent_block_style = 'do'
```

It doesn't indent exactly like I mention above, but is good enough.

```
my_method(foo: :bar,
          baz: {
            foo2: :bar2,
            foo3: :bar3,
          }
         )
```

Comment: Ya, certainly better than it was but he left the issue open since it's not perfect.

Comment: Yep. Good enough. After looking at the settings to change indent, I'm sure I don't want to wade in and try to tweak it.